# Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X "Install via usb" throws "Insert your SIM card"

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-debugging, xiaomi

I'm using a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X for my Android development.

Without "Install via USB" option, Android Studio throws:

> Installation failed with message INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER

Solution for this is enabling "Install via USB", but when I try to enable this option, phone throws Toast message "Insert your sim card". Is there any way to simulate SIM card, or just making this work?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To enable "install via usb" you have to insert sim card.

After enabling "install via usb" remove sim card then it will work without sim card also.

Comment: Thanks Xiaomi for this new feature! :/

Comment: This worked for me, even with a SIM that wasn't even activated. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: It worked for me, but unfortunately as soon as you want to install a new app (one that isn't installed on the device yet), it fails again and requires to insert a SIM card again…

Comment: Why?? Can't imagine any reason to require a SIM card to enable install over USB. Seems really dodgy.

Comment: Never gonna purchase a xiaomi device again because of this mindless implementation.

Comment: What the actual f*** Xiaomi?!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem after updating to latest MIUI 8 and it looks like there is no way to bypass the SIM requirement for now.

But you have options:

- Install previous version of MIUI. Previous version require only mi-account.
- Install another OS (ex. LineageOS)

Comment: Installing another OS is not an option without a SIM card as Xiaomi requires you to have a Sim card installed before you can unlock the Bootloader.

Answer (score -5):

Go to Settings > SIM cards & mobile networks.

Then choose a default SIM card for calls(SIM 1 or SIM 2)

And finally try again.

Comment: Unavailable if you have no SIM inserted.